# Rails: Sprockets can't find file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, sprockets

my app's working directory looks something along the lines:

```
app
 -assets
     -javascripts
          - theme
                --jquery.min.js
                --excanvas.min.js
          -- application.js
```

The application.js previously had `require_tree .`, however, it loaded excanvas.min.js before jquery.min.js. This brought up a javascript error. I would like to switch the load order. So I updated application.js to:

```
//= require unicorn/jquery.min
//= require unicorn/excanvas.min
```

However, this gave me the following error:

```
Sprockets::FileNotFound in Admin::Home#index
couldn't find file 'unicorn/jquery.min.js'
```

I was wondering why I can't seem to find jquery.min. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: had same issue ... the behaviour is inconsistent though, because in the same file, some `require`s need the ./ in the relative path and some don't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed the application.js to:

```
//= require ./unicorn/jquery.min
//= require ./unicorn/excanvas.min
```

and it seemed to work.